# Are bodybuffers efficient to relax muscles?

Tags: muscle, physiotherapy, muscle-relaxers

Are bodybuffers efficient to relax muscles? Example of bodybuffer: http://www.bellebodybuffer.com/

[image]

I am mostly interested in forarm muscles.